# fancybox overlay via api

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to setup fancyBox the first time and am struggeling with the overlay function. I want to customize it with my color but the api isn't much helpful because it just shows a solution for a link target.

My markup looks like this

```
<span class="js--fb-bla-trigger">click here</span>
<div class="js--fb-bla">content of fancybox</div>
```

and my script like this

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background-color' : '#f00'
            }
        }
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.js--fb-bla-trigger', function(){
    $.fancybox($('.js--fb-bla'));
});
```

I already know that I have to put the options/handler on my targeted element but HOW?! I tried 3 different methods, neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help instead

```
$('.js--fb-bla-trigger').on('click', function () {
    $.fancybox({
        content: $('.js--fb-bla'),
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                css: {
                    'background': '#f00'
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/5EV8r/633/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the API options after your selector like :

```
$(document).on('click', ".js--fb-bla-trigger", function () {
    $.fancybox($('.js--fb-bla'), { // notice the comma before the opening bracket
        // API options here
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                css: {
                    'background-color': '#f00'
                }
            }
        } // helpers
    }); // fancybox
}); // on click
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/azsn902a/)**